# How to fix RouterModule is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, lazy-loading

I was setting up lazy loading for my Angular 4 app. I have 18 lazy loaded modules in total, and I noticed that fetching them is taking some time, so I decided to make some kind of loading indicator.
After adding it localy to `app.component` everything was working as it should be. In production I keep getting errors about RouterModule being undefined.

[image: error]

Now I can not access none of lazy-loaded modules (those which aren't lazy loaded can be accessed without any troubles).

I tried to remove indicator and things seems to be working again.

I took code from that website https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3505-showing-a-loading-indicator-for-lazy-loaded-route-modules-in-angular-6-1-7.htm

And I assume that problem occurs when adding router to `app.component.ts` constructor.

Any help for solving that problem would be appreciated.

EDIT1:
As requested `app.routing.ts`
[image: routing]

Comment: can you show your app.routing.ts

Comment: @FatehMohamed sure, check updated original post

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize roots in a module like this:-

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: Lazy loading works OK. As you can see on screenshot above I have declared routes this way as you are saying. The problem is that loading indicator seems like breaking my app when importin Router to app.component.ts

Comment: Can you share code of constructor of app.component.ts?

Comment: Please check original post. I pasted link for website where I copied code from. My app.component.ts is the same as that one provided on link.